# MongoDB v4.0.4 user authentication passwordPrompt is not defined Error

Tags: mongodb, authentication, user-controls

am trying to authenticate Mongo database from Command Prompt, with Direct Password it's working. but as per MongoDB user auth Documentation, Trying with `passwordPrompt()`.

> Getting the Error as [js] ReferenceError: passwordPrompt is not defined. The version currently am Trying is 4.0.4.

[image]

```
db.auth("username",passwordPrompt())
```

> E QUERY    [js] ReferenceError: passwordPrompt is not defined :

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

`passwordPrompt` was not added until 4.2 and you are using Mongodb 4.0, here's where that is mentioned in the documentation:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/passwordPrompt/

Note the 'new in version 4.2'

[image: Mongodb documentation of passwordprompt]